# ROS2 Debugging Techniques

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just getting started learning ROS2 and I'm going through the tutorials. I am trying to create a subscriber to /cmd_vel. I'm working off the examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber member_functions code. All I did was change the topic name and type to /cmd_vel and geometry_msgs/Twist and I get all sorts of unhelpful errors, no line numbers, and its complaining about Strings which I don't even have in the code now.

### member_functions.cpp

```
 // Copyright 2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation, Inc.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/twist.hpp"

using std::placeholders::_1;

class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalSubscriber()
  : Node("minimal_subscriber")
  {
    subscription_ = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>(
      "/cmd_vel/managed", std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
  }

private:
  void topic_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Twist::SharedPtr msg)
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%i, %i, %i'", msg->linear[0], msg->linear[1], msg->linear[2]);
  }
  rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  RCLCPP_INFO("derp");
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

### Error

```
nick@nick-XPS-15-9550:~/ros2_overlay_ws/src/examples$ colcon build Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_client Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher      CMakeFiles/publisher_lambda.dir/lambda.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
>, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
> > > const&)': lambda.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
> >()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [publisher_lambda] Error 1 make[1]:
*** [CMakeFiles/publisher_lambda.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... CMakeFiles/publisher_not_composable.dir/not_composable.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
>, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
> > > const&)': not_composable.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
> >()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [publisher_not_composable] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_not_composable.dir/all] Error 2 CMakeFiles/publisher_member_function.dir/member_function.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
>, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_publisher_options_t const&, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
> > > const&)': member_function.cpp:(.text._ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC2EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE[_ZN6rclcpp9PublisherIN8std_msgs3msg7String_ISaIvEEES4_EC5EPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK23rcl_publisher_options_tRKSt10shared_ptrISaIS5_EE]+0x22): undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>
> >()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [publisher_member_function] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/publisher_member_function.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
--- Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher  [ Exited with code 2 ] Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client  Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_client         Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server

Summary: 0 packages finished [0.70s]   1 package failed: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher   3 packages aborted: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client   1 package had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher   8 packages not processed
```

.
.

## Update:

Per tfoote's advice I then added geometry_msgs to my CMakeLists.txt and packag.xml but now receive a new error

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)

add_executable(subscriber_lambda lambda.cpp) 
ament_target_dependencies(subscriber_lambda rclcpp std_msgs)

add_executable(subscriber_member_function member_function.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(subscriber_member_function rclcpp std_msgs geometry_msgs)

add_executable(subscriber_not_composable not_composable.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(subscriber_not_composable rclcpp std_msgs)

install(TARGETS
  subscriber_lambda
  subscriber_member_function
  subscriber_not_composable
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_package()
```

### Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format2.xsd" 
schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber</name>
  <version>0.6.1</version>
  <description>Examples of minimal subscribers</description>
  <maintainer email="jacob@openrobotics.org">Jacob Perron</maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>
  <author>Mikael Arguedas</author>
  <author>Morgan Quigley</author>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rclcpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rclcpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>


  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

### New Error

```
CMakeFiles/subscriber_member_function.dir/member_function.cpp.o: In function `rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, std::_Bind<void (MinimalSubscriber::*(MinimalSubscriber*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> > >)>, std::allocator<void>, geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(std::_Bind<void (MinimalSubscriber::*(MinimalSubscriber*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> > >)>&&, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void> >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t&) const':
/opt/ros/crystal/include/rclcpp/subscription_factory.hpp:108: undefined reference to `rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void>>>()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [subscriber_member_function] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/subscriber_member_function.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315023/ros2-debugging-techniques/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a linking error not a compile error which is why there are no line numbers. To fix that you will need to make sure to update your CMakeLists.txt to make sure to link against `geometry_msgs` in place of the examples `std_msgs`. And you'll likely need to add it as a dependency in the CMakeLists.txt at the top and in the package.xml for proper book keeping.

You'll also note that this error is for `publisher_member_function` where you look to be showing example code for the subscriber. If you want more help you'll need to help us reproduce your problem more fully. If you're only changing a few lines of the tutorial maybe a full diff of the directory would be helpful. Please edit your question to provide more information if this isn't enough to get you going.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2019-02-07**:
Ah okay. I have tried to update my CMakesLists.txt and package.xml but am still getting an error. I have updated my question with both those files.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried compiling your code and different than your case it gave me compilation errors.

After I changed one RCLCPP_INFO line in callback and commented out the one in the main function, it successfully compiled.

```
private:
  void topic_callback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Twist::SharedPtr msg)
  {
    //RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%i, %i, %i'", msg->linear[0], msg->linear[1], msg->linear[2]);
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%i, %i, %i'", msg->linear.x, msg->linear.y, msg->linear.z);
  }
  rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  //RCLCPP_INFO("derp");
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [akifusenet](https://answers.ros.org/users/39925/akifusenet/) with karma: 21 on 2019-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @tfoote pointed out, you have to add `geometry_msgs` package to the dependencies.

However, even after that, there are 2 errors in your C++ code

1. `RCLCPP_INFO("derp");`
   This is not allowed, as the first argument to RCLCPP_* should be a logger object.
2. `msg->linear[0]` this is not correct. The `linear` field of the message is of type `Vector3`, but it's not a vector.
   Look at the implementation of this type [here](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Vector3.html) and you will see that you have to access to its fields using `msg->linear.x`, `msg->linear.y`, `msg->linear.z`

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3